# Import emails from hard disk image?

Tags: server, email, postfix, cyrus

My old Pentium 3 email server just died on me. Is it possible import all my emails that I had?

I was running `postfix` and the `cyrus` IMAP server. I can chroot to the hard drive to run any commands if needed.

After `grep`'ing the hard drive, I found that all of my emails are in `/var/spool/imap`. I assume that I can't just copy all the emails to my new server, so what do I need to do to get them onto my new server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to simply rsync the /var/spool/imap from the old HDD to the new server. For that you don't need to chroot in the old HDD.

Mount your old drive in readonly mode (for safety) and use something like this (assuming you've mounted your old HDD under /mnt/old-hdd):

rsync -anv /mnt/old-hdd/var/spool/imap/ /var/spool/imap/

If you are satisfied with what rsync would do, you can re-run it without the "-n". FYI, "-n" is the "dry-run" mode of rsync.

Good luck

Comment: Awesome, I'll try that once my new server is set up :)